# Error in Canopy Installation

Tags: python-3.x, installation, canopy

I am trying to install Enthought Canopy, But it produces an error as :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9u5C.jpg)

Error writing to file

verify that you have access to the specified path

Comment: Add error text here.

Answer (score 0):

The error message screen shot shows that Windows has blocked the installer from writing to your home directory. Either you are out of disk space, or your anti-virus program is too aggressive and should be disabled for the process, or your system is mis-configured.